# How to search the word THE on Lucene CloudSearch?

Tags: lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

I need to do a query like this

`search?q="Fernando" AND area:(THE OR SAO)&q.parser=lucene`

But I think that cloudsearch is ignoring the word THE, considering that is a pronoun.

If I try this, the search works:

`search?q="Fernando" AND area:(THE)&q.parser=lucene`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the" is, by default, considered a stopword, and will be ignored.  You can configure what stopwords you want in the AnalysisOptions, as [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html#stopwords).  Simply setting stopwords to an empty array might serve your purposes:

```
"AnalysisOptions": {
    "Stopwords": "[]"
}
```